# Mixed Content HTTP / HTTPS - (GraphQL) Lighthouse is requesting an unsecured http url

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse, graphiql

After deploying to webhosting, it throws me an error on the /graphiql route to the console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myweburl.com/graphiql/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://myweburl.com/graphql/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I have the `/config/lighthouse.php` file by default

I don't know why lighthouse is asking me for an unsecured url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If your application sits behind a proxy which resolves https, the generated URL for the endpoint might not use https://, thus causing the GraphiQL UI to not work by default. In order to solve this, configure your TrustProxies middleware to contain \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR in $headers.

From [documentation](https://github.com/mll-lab/laravel-graphiql?tab=readme-ov-file#https-behind-proxy).